CMU-IKEA Kitchen object with convolutional neural network
I want to trainenter image description here the above sample dataset in convolutional network.
I trained this dataset, but the prediction accuracy of the network was just zero. Has anyone ever worked with this dataset and been able to get good accuracy?enter image description here
